# Cakephp HasMany + SaveAll doesnt work

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-model

Im trying to do a hasmany saveall() but it does not work.

I have a Model Carmodel hasMany CarmodelsImage
When i try to save, the array passed is:

```
[CarmodelsImage] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [name] => teste
                [carmodel_id] => 1
            )
    )
```

In the controller i have $this->Carmodel->saveAll($this->request->data) but it does not work.

I need some help.

I know this question was already posted but I read every answers and it not work.

Thanks

Comment: Can you clean up the formatting? What exactly happens? Throws an error? Returns false? What are the full contents of $this->request->data?

Answer (score 4):

Your requested data needs to be an array like in  the following code:

```
Array
(
   [Carmodel] => Array
                 (
                       //Carmodel fields here
                 )
   [CarmodelsImage] => Array
                      (
                       [0] => Array
                             (
                               [name] => teste
                               [carmodel_id] => 1
                             )

                       [1] => Array
                             (
                               [name] => abc
                               [carmodel_id] => 2
                             )
                       ..........
                     )
)

$this->Carmodel->saveAll($this->request->data, array('deep' => true));
```

You have to use `'deep' => true` option with saveAll() method while saving associated models details.