# How to copy a record plus its associated records to another similar table pair in Cakephp?

Tags: cakephp

I have 2 tables with a one-to-many relationship. I have another 2 similar tables with the same relationship in the same database.

How to copy a record plus its associated records from one table pair to another table pair in the same database in Cakephp?

I am using Cakephp 2.4.5

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10592610/cakephp-hasmany-saveall-doesnt-work/11338393#11338393) might help you.

You have to use `'deep' => true` option with `saveAll()` method while saving associated models details.